# Echo のクレームという概念について

Tags: go, go-echo, jwt

https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/jwt
を見ているのですが、
map claimやcustom claimとはなんでしょうか？
claimとはどういう概念でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

これは JWT での用語で、受け渡したい情報のことを表しています。JWT についてご存じなければまず [Wikipedia の記事](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)など何かしら一般的な解説をご覧ください。

以下は JWT の規格 RFC 7519 の[ドラフト版の日本語訳](https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-11.ja.html)からの引用です。

> クレーム
>   ある主体に関するひとまとまりの情報. クレームはクレーム名とクレーム値から構成される名前と値のペアで表現される.
>
> JSON Web Token (JWT)
>   クレームのセットをJSONオブジェクトとして文字列表現にしてJWSやJWEにエンコードすることで, クレームに対するデジタル署名やMACと暗号化の両方が可能になる.]

echo の JWT 用コンフィグはクレームとして dgrijalva/jwt-go の [`jwt.Claims`](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#Claims) を受け取れるように[なっており](https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/jwt)、`MapClaims` はクレームを表すために jwt-go で使われている型のひとつです。`MapClaims` は `map[string]interface{}` として JSON にデコードされるような型で、クレームを表すために使われる標準的なものです。そうではないカスタムな型を使いたい場合もあり、それが custom claims として書かれている例です。